# Adding double quotes around a string adds the closing quote on a new line

Tags: ruby

I am just starting with Ruby and working on adding double quotes around a string.

```
print "Enter the name of the file to use (including the file type)"
file_name = gets.to_s
puts "\"#{file_name}\""
```

and I get an output of

```
"test1.txt
"
```

Any ideas on what could be going wrong are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Kernel#gets](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns a string, so `.to_s` in `gets.to_s` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have to do with the quotations you're adding, but rather that you're not using [String#chomp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) to remove the trailing newline that is included with *every* `gets`:

```
gets # I type foo
# => "foo\n"

gets.chomp # I type foo
# => "foo"
```

You don't actually need the `to_s` here because `gets` will always return a string.

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thank you!